# To get user profile pic through LDAP Authentication using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

LDAP authentication is working fine for my new app and I am able to pull user details like email, full name, title, etc but not the thumbnail photo.

Thumbnail photo is in the below format :
 thumbnailPhoto:
         '����\u0000\u0010JFIF\u0000\u0001\u0001\u0001\u0000`\u0000`\u0000\u0000��\u0000C\u0000\b\u0006\u0006\u0007\u0006\u0005\b\u0007\u0007\u0007\t\t\b\n\f\u0014\r\f\u000b\u000b\f\u0019\u0012\u0013\u000f\u0014\u001d\u001a\u001f\u001e\u001d\u001a\u001c\u001c $.\' ",#\u001c\u001c(7),01444\u001f\'9=82<.342��\u0000C\u0001\t\t\t\f\u000b\f\u0018\r\r\u00182!\u001c

```
app.set('trust proxy', 1); // trust first proxy
app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: { secure: true }
}));


var user_sess = null;

function auth(req, res, next) {
  if (user_sess) {
    return next();
  } else {
    res.redirect('/');
  }
};

app.post('/auth/signin', passport.authenticate('ldapauth', { failureRedirect: '/' }), function (req, res) {
  req.session.uname = req.body.username;
  user_sess = req.session;
  res.redirect('/profile');
});

app.get('/profile', auth, (req, res) => {

 /* if (user_sess.passport.user.thumbnailPhoto.status == 200) {
    var buffer = (new Buffer(user_sess.passport.user.thumbnailPhoto.status.body.toString()));
    res.end(buffer.toString("base64")); // output content as response body

    require('fs').writeFileSync('./public/images/profilepic.jpg', buffer);  // also write it to file


    return;
  }
  console.log(buffer);
  res.writeHead(user_sess.passport.user.thumbnailPhoto.status, user_sess.passport.user.thumbnailPhoto.headers);
 res.write(user_sess.passport.user.thumbnailPhoto.body);*/



  res.render('profilesView', {
    uname: user_sess.uname,
    title: user_sess.passport.user.title,
    email: user_sess.passport.user.mail,
    //photo: buffer
  },
  );

});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("index", {
    title: "XYZ"
  });
});


app.get('/logout', function (req, res) {
  req.logout();
  user_sess = null;
  req.session.destroy();
  res.redirect('/');
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("listening port 3000");
});


I am able to render name, title, email but not the photo.
I am using below code in profile view.ejs file

 <div class="container">

      <div class="user-profilewrap">
        <!-- <img src="http://http://localhost:3000/./public/images/profilepic.jpg">-->


         <a href='/logout' style="align:right" > Logout </a>
         <h6>User Name: <%= uname %></h6>
         <h6>Email: <%= email%></h6>
         <h6>Title: <%= title %></h6>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Hi Aditya Kr, Welcome to Stack Overflow, you have not said what LDAP library your using so we don't know what we're looking at.

Comment: @MartinBarker  we are using OpenLDAP

Comment: sorry I mean what node library (module) so what are you requiring/importing E.G `const passport = require(...)` or `import passport from '...'` ) OpenLDAP is a server technology, not the client side library you're using to talk to the server

Comment: did you find a way? This is supposed to be in jpeg but I am not sure how it is converted.